# Rails I18n: Render partial with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

I wish to combine `render` function with a path declared in a .yml i18n file. My I18n .yml file follows this structure:

```
pages: 
   nav:
      items:
      - id: books
        link: 'books'
      - id: about
        link: 'about'
      - id: contact
        link: 'contact'
```

And my main layout is this one:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% t('pages.nav.items').each do |item| %>
<div id='<%= item[:id] %>'>
  <%= render item[:link] %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When I use `<% render item[:link] %>` I (obviously) get an error message as the syntax isn't correct:

`'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.`

I also tried this code:

```
<%= render "'"+item[:link].to_s+"'"%>
```

and this one:

```
<%= render partial: "'"+item[:link].to_s+"'"%>
```

But get this error as `render` seems to consider the first argument only :

```
Missing partial pages/_'', application/_'' with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

So my question is how would you suggest to combine `render` with values declared in a .yml file ?

Comment: There is no reason why you could'nt just pass the link to the render.

When you run in a ``rails c`` whats the about of this: ``I18n.t('pages.nav.items').map { |i| i[:link] }``

Comment: just use `<%= render partial: item[:link] %>`

Comment: Does array work in I18n?
I see that this issue is still open https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/281

Comment: @sovalina doesn't work either, I get "'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path." in output

Comment: did you check what `item` returns ? like `<p>"Check the #{item}"</p>` in your loop

Comment: (edit from previous answer) @stwienert I get a correct output: ["books", "about", "contact"]

Comment: @sovalina yes item returns correct array, smthg like "{:id=>"books", :link=>"books"}"

Comment: If an array is present in a view you can also try use strings in keys instead of symbols `item['link']`.
Would be easier if you provide I18n.t('pages.nav.items').inspect to see what is inside

Comment: @AlexanderSysuiev thanks for the suggestion, this is the output of `<%= I18n.t('pages.nav.items') %>` : `[{:id=>"books", :link=>"books"}, {:id=>"about", :link=>"about"}, {:id=>"contact", :link=>"contact"}]`

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the Missing partials exception? Is it possible that the exception came from a one of the 3 partials?

Try adding manually first:

``<%= render 'books' %>
<%= render 'about' %>
<%= render 'contact' %>``

Comment: @florian i'm little bit confused that's not working if you well return an hash. It should work (i tried locally in an app rails and it works)... last thing i see is trying interpolation : `<%= render partial: "#{item[:link]}" %>`

Comment: @stwienert rendered individually it does work as expected. It's the fact to loop over the list items in .yml file and use render with an array's value that triggers the aforementioned error...

Comment: @sovalina your suggestion does work ! But why ...

Comment: Can you also show output inside the each block?
`<%= item %>`
`<%= item[:id] %>`
`<%= item[:link] %>`

Comment: thanks @AlexanderSysuiev I figured this out. For some reasons the value of `link`was missing in the items list in the :fr version of my yaml file, but the key was declared. I've added a condition to make sure that when a key is declared, it has value.